# How to wipe or write zeroes to hard disk using /dev/sg2

Tags: linux, raid, smartctl

I want to wipe hard disk which is behind the raid controller. I am able to break the raid. After that, i m getting /dev/sg2 not /dev/sda like.

```
# lsscsi -g
[1:1:0:0]  disk  Hitachi HDxxxx  jp40  ---   /dev/sg2   
[1:1:1:0]  disk  SAMSUNG HDxxxx  1AA0  ---   /dev/sg3
```

so i have to write this using /dev/sg2 handle.
so what is the way to wipe the disk using /dev/sg2 handle.

Answer (score 1):

Use dd:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sg2 bs=1M
```

More secure with random bytes:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sg2 bs=1M
```

Comment: thnks for the reply. that's ok i can erase that one, but a problem is occurring that in LSI raid contoller it is showing only one that is /dev/sg0 .like                                                                                          # lsscsi -g                                                                                   [0:0:27:0] enclosu LSI Corp  SAS...    0717  --- dev/sg0                          in it there are 2 disk and it is not showing disk individually so how to wipe these disks individually.

Comment: after running this (dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sg2 bs=1M) command, i m getting error   # dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sg2 bs=1M
dd: error writing '/dev/sg2': Invalid argument
1+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 0.00156275 s, 0.0 kB/s